# Adding a link with C# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a View which is accesible `http://localhost:49467/About/` and its called `index.cshtml`.

I have another view in which is accessible by `http://localhost:49467/Food/` and is called `index2.cshtml`

I want to place a link inside the `index.cshtml` page so i could access `index2.cshtml`. How can i do it. My code;

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "Food/index" )
```

But i end up in the URL `http://localhost:49467/About/Food/` and the page is not found. All what i want to do is to navigate to `http://localhost:49467/Food/` instead. How can i correct this ?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("link", "Food/index2")` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. goes to  `../About/Food/index2` instead

Comment: Why are you using `"Food/Index2"`? Use the method properly... `@Html.ActionLink("Link Text","Index","Food")`

Answer (score 3):

'The ActionLink helper is calling a controller action, not a static URL

```
@HTML.ActionLink("linktext", "ControllerName")
```

Is your Index2.cshtml associated with the Food Contoller's Index action? If so you can do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Linktext", "Index2", "Food", null, null)
```

The third parameter above is the name of the controller for the associated action.

If `index.cshtml` is also associated with the food controller you don't need to specify the controller name:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Linktext", "Index2")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "/Food/index" )
```

note the extra slash.
Or it seems like your Routes dictate that /Food uses index2.cshtml. so you should be able to get away with

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "index2", "Food" )
```

With MVC you worry less about the file names of the views but through which controllers and actions you need to go through to get to that view.

Comment: No but, it goes to `../About/Food/index` and not to  `../Food/index2`

Comment: do you have a FoodController? And my apologies, this was off the top of my head, pulled up my mvc project to verify the edit.

Comment: Yes, i have a food controller.